# How i can insert am pm for the time based on my code or if you have how to make custom time

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I have a method that forms a time based on the minute and hour. so what I want in here is to add am pm

```
customTime(time_type, formula) {
    this.isCustomTime = true;
    let hour;
    let minute;
    if(time_type == 'hour' && formula == 'add'){    
        hour = Number(this.defaultHour) + 1;
        if(hour > 12) {
            hour = 1;
        }
        this.defaultHour = ('0' + hour).slice(-2);
    }else if(time_type == 'hour' && formula == 'minus'){    
        hour = Number(this.defaultHour) - 1;
        if(hour < 1){
            hour = 12;
        }
        this.defaultHour = ('0' + hour).slice(-2);
    }else if(time_type == 'minute' && formula == 'add'){
        minute = Number(this.defaultMinute);
        hour = Number(this.defaultHour);
        if(minute < 30) {
            minute = 30;
        }else{
            minute += 30;
            if(minute > 59) {
                minute = 0;
                hour += 1;
                if(hour > 12) {
                    hour = 1;
                }
                this.defaultHour = ('0' + hour).slice(-2);
            }
        }
        this.defaultMinute = ('0' + minute).slice(-2);
    }else if(time_type == 'minute' && formula == 'minus'){ 
        minute = Number(this.defaultMinute);
        hour = Number(this.defaultHour);
        if(minute > 30 || minute == 0) {        
            minute = 30;
            hour -= 1;
            if(hour < 1){
                hour = 12;
            }
            this.defaultHour = ('0' + hour).slice(-2);
        }else {     
            minute = 0;
        }
        this.defaultMinute = ('0' + minute).slice(-2);
    }
}
```

Note: It is working. Only the `AM/PM` of the time missing in here. So can I add those to my code or if you have some easy on how to make what I want?

Comment: how are you calling this? what are `time_type` and `formula` params?

Comment: Without context we would only be guessing.  What are you doing with this?  What time does it start at?  How is it called?  Where do you use the output?  Tons of other questions!

Comment: time_type is equal to hour or minute then formula is equal to minus or add.

Answer (score 0):

### this is the front end side of the calculation

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Home
    </ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button icon-only (click)="refresh()">
        <ion-icon name="refresh"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button icon-only (click)="showTimeZoneModal()">
        <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>

    <ion-card>

      <ion-card-header>
        {{ selectedTimeZone }}
      </ion-card-header>

      <ion-card-content>
        <div class="time">
            {{ defaultHour }} : {{ defaultMinute }} : {{ defaultSecond }} : {{ defaultMidday }}
        </div>
        <div class="date">
          {{ defaultDate }}
             <br>
          {{ defaultDay }}
        </div>
      </ion-card-content>

    </ion-card>


    <ion-card>

      <ion-card-content>

        <h2>Hour</h2>
        <button ion-item (click)="customTime('hour', 'add')"><ion-label>+</ion-label></button>
        <button ion-item (click)="customTime('hour', 'minus')"><ion-label>-</ion-label></button>

        <h2>Minute</h2>
        <button ion-item (click)="customTime('minute', 'add')"><ion-label>+</ion-label></button>
        <button ion-item (click)="customTime('minute', 'minus')"><ion-label>-</ion-label></button>

      </ion-card-content>

    </ion-card>

  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let zone of timezone; let i = index" (click)="selectTimeZone(zone, i)">
        {{ zone.name }}
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

Answer (score -1):

if you want to display time in AM/PM format then simple way is just
download/add d3 liberary from internet.

then use

```
var timeOfDay=d3.timeFormat("%H:%M:%S %p")(new Date());
console.log(timeOfDay);//your desired output
```

if you have only hours and minutes then use as bellow

```
var hour=12;
var mminutes=55;

var timeOfDay=new Date();
timeOfDay.setHours(hour);
timeOfDay.setMinutes(mminutes);
d3.timeFormat("%H:%M %p")(timeOfDay)
console.log(d3.timeFormat("%H:%M %p")(timeOfDay)
);
```

Comment: i know doing that but i have to manipulate the time without using that 1 because i want time to be customizable.